# How to insert a result of an org-mode source block as part of the document's syntax?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

Say I have the following source block:

```
#+NAME: heading
#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports none
  return "** Some outline"
#+END_SRC
```

And I insert it inlined in my buffer by using

```
* Another outline
call_heading()
```

Is it possible to specify that I want the result to be inserted as pat of the actual syntax? That is, it should appear as a new outline exactly where I inserted my call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `:results raw` will make `org-babel` insert the results of the source block literally.  You can call a named source block using the syntax `#+CALL: call_heading()`

Comment: `:results raw` was exactly what I needed. But I am aware of the `call` syntax.